# How to duplicate all folders into same directory?

Tags: 16.04

If I have thousands of folders named `a/ b/ c/` etc, how can I duplicate them and their contents multiple times such that the copied **folder** would be given a different name eg `a-copy1/ b-copy1/ c-copy1/ ... a-copy12/ b-copy12/ c-copy12/`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This script should make that possible:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash
set -e

for i in /path/to/folder
do
        if [ -d "$i" ]
        then
                for r in $(seq 1 5)
                do
                        cp -r "$i" "$i"\-copy"$r"
                done
        fi
done
```

Information:

- `for r in $(seq 1 5)`: This allows you to pick the number of copies to create.
- `if [ -d "$i" ]`: check if the target is a folder.
- `cp -r "$i" "$i"\-copy"$r"`: perform the copy.
- `set -e`: stop on first error.

Sample data:

```
a b c d e f
```

Sample output:

```
a        a-copy3  b        b-copy3  c        c-copy3  d        d-copy3  e-copy2  e-copy5  f-copy2  f-copy5
a-copy1  a-copy4  b-copy1  b-copy4  c-copy1  c-copy4  d-copy1  d-copy4  e         e-copy3  f        f-copy3
a-copy2  a-copy5  b-copy2  b-copy5  c-copy2  c-copy5  d-copy2  d-copy5  e-copy1   e-copy4  f-copy1  f-copy4
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have "thousands" of files and/or directories to process, `find` and `xargs` are the tools of choice. Read `man find` and `man xargs`.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -print0 |\
  xargs -0 --no-run-if-empty bash_script
```

Where `bash_script` is a file (mode 755), in your `$PATH` containing a user-written script to do the copying.

Answer (score 1):

Try in your directory:

```
ls | grep "pattern" | xargs -i mkdir "{}-copy1"
```

You will get all folders with the "pattern" get duplicate and rename with -copy1 at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You may write a simple bash script like:

```bash
    for i in {1..10}; do
        for dir in $(find /src/dir -maxdepth 1 -type d); do
            cp -r $dir /dst/dir/$dir-copy$i;
        done
    done
```

This snippet will make 10 copies of the directories located on /src/dir to /dst/dir